# How to kill Respawning Node

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, server

Need help for killing process node JS.
I'm trying to stop node js process on my server, 
I've been use

```
killall -9 node
```

and here is the response

```
node(30332): Operation not permitted
node: no process found
```

So I used

> sudo killall -9 node

but the node js is still respawning with different PID. Any help?

Comment: What's respawning it? Check node's parent PID.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo is there any way to check the parent PID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problems, there are Parents ID that related to Node Process.

I'm using

> ps -ef | grep no

and found the Parent Process ID / Sleep Process and kill the parents and then kill the node process.

Comment: In my case there is no parent process and kill -9 or pkill node only respawns node with a new pid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `process.kill()` or `process.exit()` to kill/stop node process internally  when there is stop request.

To stop all node process from command line use `pkill node`(in linux).

Comment: For child process use https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal