# Kill nodejs process without restart

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I have three Node.js projects that I run under `screen -r` (while testing). They ran for a long time without problems - I could easily shut them down with Ctrl+C and start them again. My problem is that now I can't shut them down.

I started the projects with a simple Node.js command:

`nodejs index.js > storage/console.log 2> storage/error.log`

It seems like that the processes were stuck in the background. The screen window got terminated after a server restart, but as soon as Ubuntu started, all the projects started to run again.

I tried to kill them with `kill -9 {id}` and `killall nodejs`, I even tried to shut them down in `htop`, but they restarted anyway. Additionally, it seems like one project is running in several instances at a time, thus my CPU is on 100% all the time.

Can somebody help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you didn't kill the parent process and so the child gets re-spawned every time? Maybe this will help [How to kill Respawning Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382188/how-to-kill-respawning-node)

Comment: This is one of my projects (ps -ef | grep no): 
"root     16156     1  1 11:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr//bin/nodejs /root/project1/index.js"
"root     16196 16156  6 11:41 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/nodejs /root/project1/index.js".

I tried kill 16156 with "kill -9 16156" command but they restart with new id

Comment: using **ps axf** you can see the tree of processes. You can use it to see if there is a parent process that may be respawning the children

Comment: Looking some more into the issue it may be that it is a problem related to this thread (updated just 13 days ago) https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4182